# Multivariable Probability Distributions, solving for probability of another function

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am self-learning probability and statistics through a textbook and I'm currently pretty successful but these problems have always confused me - I've never really seen one effective way to do them.

E.g

$$\text{ we have two random variables}, X_1, \text{ and } X_2, \text{ which both have uniform distributions and have the bounds} $$

$$0 < X < 1/2$$
$$2/3 < Y < 5/6$$

$$\text {What is the probability that X + Y > 1?} $$

I know how to approach questions where we transform BOTH X and Y, where you use change-of-variables techniques, but I never understood how to do it when you just had one.

If someone could walk me through this specific example, but also explain a general way to do these kinds of problems?

Comment: Why don't you try drawing a graph ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of problems are better dealt geometrically.

Draw the inequalities

[image: Geom_prob_1]

Then it is clear that what you are looking for is the area
of the trapetium $EBCF$ divided by the area of the rectangle $ABCD$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Awesome graphic. I ended up solving the problem like that, but it is such a relief that it's not a weird tactic to use! Thank you.

Comment: @DownstairsPanda I am glad to have make things clear to you